# tkinter: Placing a text field inside a frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a frame and i wanted to place a text field inside.
This is my code:

```
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bg='#80c1ff') #remove color later
frame2.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, relheight=1, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')

text_frame=Frame(frame2)
text_frame.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.9, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
text=Text(text_frame)
text.place(relx=0, rely=0, relheight=0.9, relwidth=1, anchor='nw')
```

However, i am getting an error at this code:

```
  File "mySerial.py", line 97, in <module>
    text_frame=Frame(frame2)
NameError: name 'Frame' is not defined
```

How should i modify the `text_frame=Frame(frame2)` line, in order to make it have the frame2 as parent?

Comment: change that line to `text_frame = tk.Frame(frame2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you imported tkinter using `import tkinter as tk`. That means that every time you want to create a new widget/tkinter object you need to write `tk.<object name>` instead of `<object name>`. Therefore to fix your issue change `text_frame=Frame(frame2)` to `text_frame = tk.Frame(frame2)`.